# Add where statement to database query

Tags: php, joomla3.8

I need to modify the database query to not select a certain ID in the database so the items with that ID do not show in the results. However, I cannot figure out how to do this. below I added a WHERE statement but I don't know if this is the right way to do this or if it is even created correctly.

->where ('geo.fid' != 887)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
protected function loadEntries( &$data, $conditions )
    {
        $db = SPFactory::db();
        $table = $db->join( array(
                array( 'table' => 'spdb_field_geo', 'as' => 'geo', 'key' => 'sid' ),
                array( 'table' => 'spdb_object', 'as' => 'spo', 'key' => 'id' )
        ) );
        if ( Sobi::My( 'id' ) ) {
            $this->userPermissionsQuery( $conditions, 'spo.' );
        }
        else {
            $conditions = array_merge( $conditions, array( 'spo.state' => '1', '@VALID' => $db->valid( 'spo.validUntil', 'spo.validSince' ) ) );
        }
        $data[ 'entries' ] = SPFactory::db()
                ->select( array( 'geo.sid', 'geo.latitude', 'geo.longitude' ), $table, $conditions )

                ->where ('geo.fid' != 887) // this is what I am trying to add but it breaks the code.

                ->loadAssocList();
        Sobi::Trigger( 'SPGeoMap', 'AfterGetEntries', array( &$data[ 'entries' ] ) );
        $data[ 'count' ] = count( $data[ 'entries' ] );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this portion of code from https://github.com/Sigsiu-NET/SobiPro/blob/master/Site/lib/base/config.php :

[image]

I'll recommend this possible solution:

```
if (Sobi::My('id')) {
    $this->userPermissionsQuery($conditions, 'spo.');
} else {
    $conditions = array_merge($conditions, array('spo.state' => '1', '@VALID' => $db->valid('spo.validUntil', 'spo.validSince')));
}
$conditions = array_merge($conditions, array('!geo.fid' => '887'));

$data['entries'] = SPFactory::db()
         ->select(array('geo.sid', 'geo.latitude', 'geo.longitude'), $table, $conditions)
         ->loadAssocList();
```

It seems your earlier-used numeric values are single-quote wrapped, but the sourced code snippet does not bother with quoting integer values -- so you may be able to leave the value unquoted.

I say all this with absolutely no personal experience with this product; I am merely joining you on this researching quest.  Do let us know how this pans out.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `!=` is wrapped in the quotes. Also escape the column name, like so:

```
->where($db->quoteName('geo.fid') . ' != 887');
```

Comment: Thank you for corrections. However whenever I add the WHERE statement it breaks the code. This code loads markers onto a google map. Perhaps I should not be trying to do this with a WHERE statement. I have 14 geolocation fields that load onto the map - but there is one, fid 887, that I don't want to load onto the map. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user1701282 - Try putting a semicolon at the end of it

Comment: @Lodder Where is the manual on SPFactory?  That `select()` method looks wrong, but maybe I'm looking up the wrong docs.  Is it a non-Joomla thing?  Does the `where` condition belong up in the `$conditions` declaration?

Comment: @mickmackusa - I can only assume `SPFactory` is a mimic of Joomla's `JFactory` from the SobiPro extension or something. The `select` clause does look incorrect completely. Perhaps The approach is supported with `SPFactory::db()`....not sure.

Comment: @mickmackusa - No worries, all done

Comment: According to the OP and a snippet that I dug up, this product does not expect the same format as Joomla query methods.  This `select()` method's 3rd parameter expects an associative array and, oddly, the `NOT` distinction is declared by prepending the `key` with `!`.  So it seems your suggestion will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I have success with the following format

```
->select($db->quoteName(array('geo.sid', 'geo.latitude', 'geo.longitude')), $table, $conditions );

->where($db->quoteName('geo.fid') . ' <> 887 ' . );
```

Comment: According to the OP and a snippet that I dug up, this product does not expect the same format as Joomla query methods.  This `select()` method's 3rd parameter expects an associative array and, oddly, the `NOT` distinction is declared by prepending the `key` with `!`.  So it seems your suggestion will not work.